# SBT not resolving mysql dependency play framework

Tags: mysql, playframework, dependencies, sbt

I tried to install play framwork 2.1.0 and using an sql server and MySQLWorkBench for having access to the database. I'm using java also.

Actually on my laptop, everyhting is working well, but on my company desktop, I cannot run my app, because there are unresolved dependencies, play can't find the mysql connector 5.1.18.

I've looked up for many solutions and seems to be a proxy issue. This is the same case than this topic : [SBT not resolving Squeryl dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963101/sbt-not-resolving-squeryl-dependency)

It ended to be a proxy problem but no one says how to resolve it (I have the proxy server address and the port)?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Cheers

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "myApplication"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean
  )

   val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  )

}
```

I've looked deeper, there is still this proxy issue, but I figure a way to download the mysql-connector-java manually into the repository of play, but then when running, it still tries to download the connector from the web and does not use the one I've download.

Do ou know how to tell play console to go directly to my connector instead of looking for one on the web?

Cheers

Comment: Please add your Build.scala.

Answer (score 0):

It was a proxy issue, I had to add an environnement variable http_proxy and the name is : hhtp://addressoftheproxy. Don't forget http, that is what was missing.